# I'm trying to make a small program where the user enters a filename, and the name of the file is written into the txt file

Tags: c++, string, file, filenames

I'm trying to make it so the user enters a filename e.g. "Hello", and a file with that file name is created e.g. "Hello.txt", and the name of the file is also written into the file, so the contents will also be "Hello". I've been trying for hours to find a solution but no luck (Sorry, I'm new to this) 
Code below.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <fstream>


    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {

    ofstream file;
    string filename;

    file.open("/Users/anthonykerr/Desktop");

    cout << "Please enter a file name to write: ";
    cin >> filename;

    file << filename << endl;

    file.close();

    cout << filename << endl;

    return 0;
```

Comment: So when you call `file.open(...)`, which file do you open?

Comment: Well, you are missing to create that file or what??

Comment: Don't use `file.open` or `file.close`. As per the RAII principle the file will close when it goes out of scope at the end of the program. Just use `ofstream file{"/Users/anthonykerr/Desktop/"+filename};` (which will also open the file) after `cin >> filename;`.

Comment: What happens? What does not happen? Please describe the observed behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using `freopen`. It redirects a stream to a file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string filename;
    std::cin >> filename;

    //using freopen: 
    //              filename.c_str() is filename converted to char sequnce
    //              "w" means, that the file is opened in "write" mode
    //              stdout is the stream redirected to file
    std::freopen(filename.c_str(), "w", stdout);

    //cout was redirected to file, so filename is written in the file
    std::cout << filename;
    return 0;
}
```